# How to get the correct output when using batch forecasting for the monthly time series with the Mcomp package?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, smoothing

I'm trying to do batch forecasting for the monthly time series with the `Mcomp` package. I've prepared a code but I am not getting any output.

```
library(forecast)    
library(Mcomp)
```

Using the `seq` function, as I need to select the particular time series which ends with 7.

```
tsset <- (seq(1507, 2797, 10)) 
tsset

horizon <- 18
fit1<-array(0,130)

for (tsi in 1:130){
  y <- tsset[[tsi]]$x
  yt <- head(y, length(y) - horizon)
  yv <- tail(y, horizon)

  for(i in 1:130){
    fit1 <-c(ets(yt))
  }
  print(fit1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you get the prediction for the last 18 points, given the first 112 points in the time series (you don't need loops):

```
tsset<- seq(1507, 2797, 10) + 10*runif(130) # add noise
horizon <- 18

y <- tsset
n <- length(y)
yt <- head(y, n - horizon)
#yv <- tail(y, horizon)
fit1 <- ets(yt)
yv1 <- forecast(fit1, h=horizon)

start <- n - horizon + 1
plot(start:n, yv, type='l', col='red', lty=1, xlab='t', ylab='y(t)')
lines(start:n, yv1$mean, col='blue', lty=2)
lines(start:n, yv1$upper[,2], col='green', lty=2)
lines(start:n, yv1$lower[,2], col='green', lty=2)
legend("topleft", legend=c("original", "forecast", "95% CI"),
                  col=c("red", "blue", "green"), lty=c(1,2,2), cex=0.8)
```

[image]